# Navigate relative to submodule in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have some nested modules with different url prefixes. Now I want to navigate within one module without specifying the prefix (in my module I do not want to know under which prefix the module is accessible).

These are the routes for my app.module:

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            { path: '', component: MainComponent },
            { path: 'nested', loadChildren: 'app/nested/nested.module#NestedModule' }
        ]
    }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, { useHash: true });
```

These are the routes for my nested.module:

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: NestedComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', component: NestedSubComponent },
            { path: 'sub', component: NestedSubComponent },
            { path: 'sub/:id', component: NestedSubComponent }
        ]
    }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forChild(APP_ROUTES);
```

Now I want for example to navigate from /#/nested/sub to /#/nested/sub/123. How can I achieve this? I do not know how deep I am nested in my submodule (i.e. if my subroute is / or /sub or /sub/:id) and also I do not want to use the nested prefix as I want to have a generic solution which can be used for other submodules, too.

Answer (score 6):

You can use second parameter of `Router.navigate()` method to specify `relativeTo` option, then it will navigate relatively to that route.

```
constructor(private router: Router, 
            private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

goDeeper() {
    this.router.navigate(['next-nested-route'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
}

goBack() {
    this.router.navigate(['../'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
}
```

You can also use `routerLink` directive, which has `ActivatedRoute` set implicitly, just do not put there the first slash.

```
<a routerLink="/next">absolute</a>
<a routerLink="next">relative next</a>
<a routerLink="..">relative back</a>
```

More about this in angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/router#!#relative-navigation

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that I can use the relativeTo property, but depending on my nesting level (which I don't know) I would need to use different paths. For instance if my ActivatedRoute is "/", I would use "sub/123" and if it is "/sub" I would use "/123". So what I want is a Route relative to NestedComponent.

Comment: The point of this is that you can use `relativeTo` inside a component to navigate to its child route. If you want to have the same component on different level of nesting, the only way would be to use absolute path...

Comment: Or you could manually get the right route from `ActivatedRoute` object and use that (you can get `parent`, `root` or `children` from `ActivatedRoute`, that should also be instance of `ActivatedRoute`).

Comment: Getting the right route manually from the ActivatedRoute was something I also thought about. But this would require me to somehow annotate the route in my routing.ts as I wouldn't know which is the right route otherwise. Or is there any way to detect if the current route is the root route for any submodule?

Comment: You can define the route like this `{ path: 'privacy', component: PrivacyComponent, data: { id: 'privacy', title: 'PRIVACY' } },` and access the `data` on `ActivatedRoute` later (and look up the value you are looking for).

Comment: Yes, that was what I thouht about, probably it will not work without adding a data attribute.

Comment: I have opened an according feature-request on github https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36514